# returning true with an occurance of a letter in a string?

Tags: java

it should return true as there is 'c' in the string S but it keeps returning False?

```
public class A {
public static void main(String[] args){

  System.out.println(contains('c', "cccc"));
}



  public static boolean contains(char c, String s) {
      boolean to_return = true;
    while(true) {
      if(s.equals("")){
      return to_return = false;
  } else {
      char c2 = s.charAt(0);
      if(c==c2) { 
      to_return = true; 
      }
  }

      s=s.substring(1);
    }

  }


}
```

I have NO idea why it isnt? it only returns false if the string is empty which is clearly is(I am NOT allowed to use for loops etc..

Comment: Look at how many return statements you've got. How could it ever return `true`? Note that `return to_return = false;` is equivalent to `to_return = false; return false;`

Comment: is `String.contains()` not good enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

you are not returning `true` anywhere in your code. So recursion happens till `s.equals("")` is evaluated to `true` and returns `false`.

Change

```
  if(c==c2) { 
  to_return = true; 
  }
```

to

```
  if(c==c2) { 
  return true; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

works:

```
public static boolean contains(char c, String s) {
    return s.indexOf(c) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a loopy version, use a for loop like this, as it should be cleaner:

```
public static boolean contains(char c, String s) {
    boolean to_return = true;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != c) {
            to_return = false;
        }
    }
    return to_return;

}
```

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
public static boolean contains2(char c, String s) {
    return s.contains(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a more cleaner method, it seems too cluttered.

```
public static boolean contains(char c, String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return false;

    if (s.equals(""))
        return false;

    int size = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) == c)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```